# Is ColorDistance symmetric?

Tags: color, distance

Is the function `ColorDistance` symmetric, i.e. is it always true that `ColorDistance[a,b] == ColorDistance[b,a]`, as use of the word *distance* would suggest?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on the `DistanceFunction` used.

`"CIE76"` and `"CIE2000"` are symmetric.  However, `"CIE94"` and `"CMC"` are not.

```
ColorDistance[##, DistanceFunction -> "CIE76"] & @@@ {{Red, Blue}, {Blue, Red}}
(* {1.8401283, 1.8401283} *)

ColorDistance[##, DistanceFunction -> "CIE94"] & @@@ {{Red, Blue}, {Blue, Red}}
(* {0.73824131, 0.65806887} *)

ColorDistance[##, DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] & @@@ {{Red, Blue}, {Blue, Red}}
(* {0.55797554, 0.55797554} *)

ColorDistance[##, DistanceFunction -> "CMC"] & @@@ {{Red, Blue}, {Blue, Red}}
(* {1.1576119, 0.8386259} *)
```

Many applications that use some sort of distance function, such as clustering, assume the distance function to be symmetric.  It is important to use a symmetric colour distance for these.  `FindClusters` uses `ColorDistance` for colours by default.  The default `DistanceFunction` for `ColorDistance` is the symmetric `"CIE76"`.

Comment: I've worked with color before and I am still surprised by this.  I should probably look into this myself but I'm feeling lazy; *why* are some of these functions asymmetric?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "Because they're defined that way." Well, why they are defined that way? I don't know the answer to that, but if we look at the definition of, say, [CIE94 distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94), it's apparent that $S_C$ and $S_H$ depend only on one color, not both.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's why I posted it.  I thought others would be surprised too and just assume symmetry without checking.  It's not a bug BTW.

Comment: BTW, if you want to lose a bit more faith on color distance functions, please read http://www.ece.rochester.edu/~gsharma/ciede2000/ciede2000noteCRNA.pdf (The CIEDE2000 Color-Difference Formula: Implementation Notes, Supplementary Test Data, and Mathematical Observations), especially the part on discontinuities. "[...] the discontinuities do preclude the use of the formula in analysis based on Taylor series approximations and in design techniques using gradient based optimization, that not only require continuity of the function but also continuity of the first derivative."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One reason is because it makes the functions less complex — they can apply whatever corrections they need based on one color, instead of at some kind of midpoint between two colors. My understanding is also that the asymmetrical ones are used for measuring the impact of a small area of color B on a large background of color A, where the assymetry might actually be appropriate, assuming that the visual system mostly accommodates to A.

Comment: @MrWizard I asked someone who researches perception and I was told that these measures are not particularly meaningful for large distances.  They're meant for comparing colours that are relatively close.  In this case the asymmetry is much less pronounced.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes. I have been experimenting with `ColorDistance` for quite a while, mostly to find aestetically well separable colors - and I must say result are not as neat as variance minimization algorithms would imply. Measures that would be useful on this context would be interesting to see!

Comment: @Szabolcs Here's an example of five colors which are almost exactly at the same distance, pairwise according to CIEDE2000: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Jxy.png - it's quite clear that some of these are more separable from each other than others. It would be interesting to know if there are color distance functions also designed to make sense for large color differences, not just small ones.

Comment: I have never thought about this before. This is scary! _"They're meant for comparing colours that are relatively close"_ - it sounds like color distance should be defined in a higher dimensional space maybe?