# How to sort colors properly?

Tags: color, sorting

I can't seem to be able to sort colors by their hue and perceptual brightness correctly. Here's my current solution, but it's not right; there are all these dark bands:

```
c = RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _], 500];
o1 = SortBy[c, ColorConvert[#, "HSB"][[1]] &];
o2 = SortBy[c, ColorConvert[#, "LAB"][[2]] &];
Image[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {Table[o1, {100}], Table[o2, {100}]}
```

[image: my attempt to sort colors]

I want to find a way to achieve color sorting that minimizes these bands and smooths the transition along the gradient, something similar to the clustering histograms [Theo Gray used in the Disney app](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/08/13/a-visit-to-disneys-magic-kingdom/).

[image: clustering histograms]

Comment: Both your solutions are right. The dark and light bands are to be expected. The first sorts by hue, regardless of brightness, and it does exactly that; the brightness is not taken into account in the sort. The same happens for your a* sort.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for is a clustering that minimizes those discontinuities.

Comment: Interesting. That reduces it to a traveling salesman problem, where the distance metric is CIELAB, rather than Euclidean. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I see that "CIE2000" is an option for DistanceFunction, but I can't find a list of other ones :(

Comment: ***Unfortunately this idea runs into a basic problem: You can’t sort colors. Because the human eye has three distinct color sensors (red, green, and blue), color is fundamentally a three-dimensional quantity, and there is no linear ordering that brings together “similar” colors. If you sort first by amount of red, for example, then you may bring together wildly different hues and brightnesses. If you sort by hue, then you bring together wildly different degrees of saturation and brightness, and so on. There’s just no way to do it.***  -- the article you cite

Comment: The article also describes how Mr. Gray created the histograms you like, so you could try doing that.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't the sorting routine, but rather the RGB color classification system is inadequate to fully describe a color.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to sort the colors in such a way as to make them seem the least discontinuous, then one way to think of it is that each color is a point in a space endowed with a distance metric (either the CIELAB 1976 or the CIELAB2000 perceptual metrics), and you are trying to find a shortest tour that visits each point. We can do that with `ColorDistance` and `FindShortestTour`:

```
c = RandomColor[500];
ord2000 = 
  FindShortestTour[c, 
    DistanceFunction -> (ColorDistance[#1, #2, 
        DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] &)][[2]];
ord76 = FindShortestTour[c, DistanceFunction -> ColorDistance][[2]];
Image[Table[c[[ord2000]], {100}]]
Image[Table[c[[ord76]], {100}]]
```

Giving the following two results:

[image]
[image]

To my eye, it looks like the CIE2000 metric does a slightly better job than the older 1976 variant.

As Mr. Wizard points out, "sorting" colors is sort of like "sorting" random points in a space with more than one dimension: there's no general way to do it that makes sense, since you're trying to impose a linear order on something which has more than one dimension. So the best you can do is find a shortest tour.

Comment: A pleasing result indeed.  By the way I think this is relevant: [Is ColorDistance symmetric?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86730/121)

Answer (score 17):

Just for fun, how does a 3D Hilbert curve sample the 3D colourspace of RGB? and can it be used to sort colours?

`HilbertCurve3D[n]` generates a 3D Hilbert curve of order `n`. The code is by Michael Trott from page 93 of The Mathematica Guidebook for Programming.

```
HilbertCurve3D[n_Integer?Positive] :=
   Module[{axiom = "X", recursion = "X" -> {"t", "c", "X", "F", "t", "c", "X", "F",
           "X", "q", "F", "t", "d", "d", "X", "F", "X", "w", "F", "p", "d",
           "d", "X", "F", "X", "q", "F", "d", "X", "q", "d"},
           r = {0, 0, 0}, m = IdentityMatrix[3]},
          Prepend[ DeleteCases[ Which[ (*the movements*)
             # == "F", r = r + (First /@ m),
             # == "B", r = r - (First /@ m);,
             # == "w", m = m.{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}};,
             # == "t", m = m.{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};,
             # == "p", m = m.{{0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};,
             # == "q", m = m.{{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};,
             # == "c", m = m.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}};,
             # == "d", m = m.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 0}};,
             True, Null] & /@ Flatten[Nest[# /. recursion &,
                                 Characters[axiom], n]], Null], {0, 0, 0}]]
```

`HilberCurve3D[n]` returns all points with integer coordinates within a cube spanning $\{0,0,0\}$ to $(2^n-1)*\{1,1,1\}$. Normalize by dividing by $2^n-1$ so that all coordinates range between 0 and 1. The number of samples in `HilbertCurve3D[n]` is $2^{3n}$.

The following code finds points on the Hilbert curve nearest the random colours, and sorts the colours based on the point position along the curve.

```
Block[{randomColours, rgbList, n = 3, hcurve, nearestFunction, 
       nearestHilbertIndex, sortedColours},

       (* make random colours *)
       randomColours = RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _], 500];

       (* create triples of rgb values, ranging 0 to 1 *)
       rgbList = Apply[List, randomColours, 1];

       (* normalized 3D Hilbert curve ranging 0 to 1 *)
       hcurve = HilbertCurve3D[n]/(2^n-1.);

       (* form nearest function for Hilbert curve *)
       nearestFunction = Nearest[hcurve -> Automatic];

       (* find index of Hilbert point nearest each random colour *)
       nearestHilbertIndex = Flatten[nearestFunction[rgbList], 1];

       (* sort random colours *)
       sortedColours = SortBy[
          Transpose[{randomColours, nearestHilbertIndex}], Last][[All, 1]];

       (* display random and sorted colours *)
       {Image[Table[randomColours, {100}], ImageSize -> 400], 
        Image[Table[sortedColours, {100}], ImageSize -> 400]} // Column
]
```

[image: random colours]

[image: sorted colours]

Comment: Since you're going down this route: you could also try sorting the colors in Morton order.

Comment: BTW, you could use `Ordering[]` to rearrange the colors instead of going through the trouble of making an array for `SortBy[]`: `randomColours[[Ordering[nearestHilbertIndex]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Palm to forehead. Thank you for your consistently valuable comments on many of the questions here.

Answer (score 12):

I've decided to follow through on my suggestion in a comment to Kenny's answer to use Morton ordering (a.k.a. Z-ordering) of the colors in RGB space.

Here's a short routine to generate the `n`-th iterate of a `d`-dimensional Z-curve:

```
Morton[d_Integer, n_Integer] :=
   Array[FromDigits[BitGet[#1, d Range[n - 1, 0, -1] + #2], 2] &,
         {2^(n d), d}, {0, 0}]/(2^n - 1)
```

Let's generate a few random colors:

```
(* for reproducibility *)
cols = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; RandomReal[1, {500, 3}]];
Graphics[Raster[{cols}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1/8}}]]
```

[image: random colors]

Now, we proceed in a manner similar to Kenny's take, but using Morton ordering:

```
nf3 = Nearest[Morton[3, 3] -> Automatic];
idx = Flatten[nf3 /@ cols];
Graphics[Raster[{cols[[Ordering[idx]]]}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1/8}}]]
```

[image: Morton-sorted colors]

Nice banding, it looks. Whether this will suit OP's needs is an entirely different question...

Comment: Other possibilities, apart from the use of a different space-filling curve, would be to consider the Morton or Hilbert ordering in a different colorspace, like XYZ.

Answer (score 10):

I will use `FeatureSpacePlot` to do this.Plot their in feature space

```
colors = RandomColor[100];
```

This is original order

[image]

```
fea = FeatureSpacePlot[colors]
```

[image]

Sort it by `DimensionReduce`

```
Row[Keys[Sort[<|
    Thread[Cases[fea, _RGBColor, Infinity] -> 
      Flatten[DimensionReduce[
        Cases[fea, Text[___, x_List, _] :> x, Infinity], 1]]]|>]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Might be better to use `DimensionReduce[]` directly, since that's what `FeatureSpacePlot[]` uses internally: `ord = Flatten[DimensionReduce[colors, 1, Method -> "TSNE", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]]; Row[colors[[Ordering[ord]]]]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.That's better than me.

Comment: @yode J. M.'s shortcut doesn't preserve the color orderings!

Comment: This thread is top of DuckDuckGo search for "color sort". Mathematics is a good way to **evenly** sort colors. nCol is a new color format at [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_ncol.asp). Sine calculations dominating this thread skew all primaries (i've tried dozens of dozens of models), that skew is toxic. So dump it! Yode citation '1]]]' indicates need for tangent analysis. Thanks yode! Using the nCol color block, namely RYGCBM. `nCol ⱭN, w%, b%`, e.g., C0,0%,0%, so where sum = w% + b%, then Ɑ[100((1+∑)/((1+∑)cos) + Ntan)] If it is not asking too much, please test nCOL sc