# How to get a scaled density plot for a custom color function?

Tags: function-construction, color

I have considered 12 major colours to design my custom colour function.

```
colors = {Black, Blue, Purple, Red, Brown, Gray, Green, Orange, Pink, 
   Cyan, Yellow, White};
```

I've sorted them based on their corresponding grey values using the formula:
`value = 0.2989 * Red + 0.5870 * Green + 0.1140 * Blue`

and I have got the corresponding values:

```
positions = {0.0000, 0.1140, 0.20645, 0.2989, 0.43694, 0.50000, 
   0.5870, 0.5924, 0.6494, 0.7010, 0.8859, 1.0000};
```

When I plot the colour values as a density plot, I get the following

[image]

But I want to use the `positions` as well to get the 12 colours at those positions in a 0 to 1 scale and the rest of the values should get interpolated accordingly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you noticed [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html)?

Comment: Does this helps: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, +Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thick, Dashed], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[colors, #] &)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html)

[image]

```
colors = 
 {Black, Blue, Purple, Red, Brown, Gray, Green, Orange, Pink, Cyan, Yellow, White};

w = List @@@ ColorConvert[colors, "RGB"] . {0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140}

colorfn = Evaluate[Blend[{w, colors}\[Transpose], #]] &;

DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.1, ColorFunction -> colorfn]
```

[image]

By the way this question may be of tangential interest:

- [How to sort colors properly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87588/121)