# Locating Points "orderly" within a cube

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a small question about creating a 3D array of particles. It's necessary that 265 particles are located orderly within a unit cube. One hint is to use a simple cubic structure but I don't see how to realize that.
So I'm looking for some commands to distribute the particles with the same distance to all it's neighbors but I have no ideas how to do that.

Comment: Look for Tuples

Comment: Why not a simple array of $8 \times 8 \times 8$ particles?

Comment: `Graphics3D[Point[SpherePoints[265]]]` ?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci:  The OP wants a 3D array using "a simple cubic structure" to *fill* a unit cube—not cover a sphere.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible since` 265^(1/3)=6.42316` particles per side of the cube which is not a whole number..

Comment: It's not clear to me that everyone know what the technical definition "located orderly" is.  I can see from google that it's a term in science journal articles, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825641/how-to-generate-a-set-of-k-points-evenly-spaced-in-unit-cube-sphere-of-dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code `HilbertCurve3D[n]` by Michael Trott (page 93 of The Mathematica Guidebook for Programming) from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-sort-colors-properly/87672#87672) question. Given input `n`, the function returns $2^{3n}$ orderly points within the cube from {0,0,0} to {1,1,1}. Use `RandomSample` to select 265, or any number, of these points.

```
Graphics3D[
   Point[RandomSample[HilbertCurve3D[3], 265]],
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]
]
```

[image: random sample of unit cube]

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and `Graphics3D[Point[RandomSample[Tuples[Range[0, 1, 1/7], 3], 265]], 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]`

Comment: Well I think these two solution are as good as it gets to solve further problems. Simple Cubic with some vacancy defect should do it too. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

What about $265$ points sampled uniformly from the cube?  *Somewhat* orderly!

```
Graphics3D[Point /@ (Flatten@Table[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[],RandomReal[]},{265}])]
```

[image: 265 points in cube]

Comment: Yes. This gives me a nice grid but with 512 instead of 265 particles.