# Sorting colors in the plotstyle versus the grade of details

Tags: plotting, color, sorting

We have multi plots in a figure that are shown individually with specific colors.

```
Plot[{Sin[x^2], Sin[x^0.7], Cos[x^2], Cos[x^0.5]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {
 CMYKColor[0.3, 0.7, 0, 0.2], 
 CMYKColor[0.9, 0.5, 0, 0.0], 
 CMYKColor[0.98, 0.7, 0.5, 0.0], 
 CMYKColor[0.8, 0.15, 0.2, 0.1]}]
```

We are going to sort the colors of the plots versus for example `Cyan` grade. I mean in this format:

```
 Plot[{Sin[x^2], Sin[x^0.7], Cos[x^2], Cos[x^0.5]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {
 CMYKColor[0.98, 0.7, 0.5, 0.0],
 CMYKColor[0.9, 0.5, 0, 0.0], 
 CMYKColor[0.8, 0.15, 0.2, 0.1],
 CMYKColor[0.3, 0.7, 0, 0.2]}]
```

Instead, for the grade of `Magenta`, `CMYKColor[0.98, 0.7, 0.5, 0.0]` or `CMYKColor[0.3, 0.7, 0, 0.2]` can be the first but definitely `CMYKColor[0.8, 0.15, 0.2, 0.1]` is the last one.

We do not know how do we apply the `Sort` command to reach the aim!!! Is there another way to this aim!?

In the [address](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-sort-colors-properly) there is a way to sort colors, while we did not understand its solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
colors = {CMYKColor[0.3, 0.7, 0, 0.2], CMYKColor[0.9, 0.5, 0, 0.0], 
  CMYKColor[0.98, 0.7, 0.5, 0.0], CMYKColor[0.8, 0.15, 0.2, 0.1]}
```

[image]

Reverse sort by `Cyan` component:

```
SortBy[-#[[1]] &] @ colors
(* or colors[[Ordering[-colors[[All, 1]]]]] *)
```

[image]

Reverse sort by `Magenta` component:

```
SortBy[-#[[2]] &] @ colors
(* or colors[[Ordering[-colors[[All, 2]]]]] *)
```

[image]